# Умные указатели C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Есть такой код:

```
_object = std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object());
```

Если мне понадобилось, чтобы объект стал пустым то я сделаю так:

```
_object = nullptr;
```

А потом снова хочу эту переменную использовать и вызову снова

```
_object = std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object());
```

Вопрос: будет ли утечка памяти и правильно ли так делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утечки не будет, где ей взяться? Создавать `std::shared_ptr` лучше с использование `std::make_shared`, это позволяет иметь блок подсчёта ссылок и сами данные одним куском в памяти. Т.е. код будет выглядеть так:

```
_object = std::make_shared<Object>();
```